# What is the general form of the particular solution guaranteed to exist by Theorem 6 of the linear nonhomogeneous recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the linear non homogeneous recurrence relation $$a_n=c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}+\cdots+c_ka_{n-k}+F(n),$$ where $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k$ are real numbers, and $$F(n)=\left(b_tn^t+b_{t-1}n^{t-1}+\cdots+b_1n+b_0\right)s^n,$$ where $b_0,b1,\dots,b_t$ and $s$ are real numbers. When $s$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the associated linear homogeneous recurrence relation, there is a particular solution of the form $$\left(p_tn^t+p_{t-1}n^{t-1}+\cdots+p_1n+p_0\right)s^n.$$ When $s$ is a root of this characteristic equation and its multiplicity is $m$, there is a particular solution of the form $$n^m\left(p_tn^t+p_{t-1}n^{t-1}+\cdots+p_1n+p_0\right)s^n.$$

> What is the general form of the particular solution guaranteed to exist by this theorem of the linear nonhomogeneous recurrence relation $$a_n = 6a_{n−1} −12a_{n−2} +8a_{n−3} +F(n)$$ if…
>
> a) $F(n) = n^2$
> b) $F(n) =2^n$
> c) $F(n) = n2^n$